# Insert multiple rows using select with a customised column

Tags: mysql

I want to clone the data of customer 1 (Alex) in the same table but with customer 2 (TOM):

```
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------+
| ID | Customer | INPUT | OUTPUT |  WIN  |
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Alex     | test1 | test2  | test3 |
|  2 | Alex     | test5 | test8  | test8 |
+----+----------+-------+--------+-------+
```

This did't work :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (Customer,INPUT,OUTPUT,WIN) 
VALUES "TOM", (SELECT INPUT,OUTPUT,WIN FROM my_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the changed value in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (Customer,INPUT,OUTPUT,WIN) 
 SELECT "TOM", INPUT,OUTPUT,WIN FROM my_table;
```

I'd also add `WHERE`

```
INSERT INTO my_table (Customer,INPUT,OUTPUT,WIN) 
 SELECT "TOM", INPUT,OUTPUT,WIN FROM my_table WHERE Customer='Alex';
```